# Points above a $k$-rational point have trivial stabilizer in algebraic fundamental group of the base change to $\bar{k}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a perfect field with a fixed algebraic closure $\bar{k}$, $X$ an integral proper normal $k$-curve, $U \subset X$ open and non-empty. Assume that $X$ is geometrically integral and that $p \in U$ is $k$-rational. Take some pro-point $\tilde{q}$ of $\tilde{X}$, the profinite branched cover of $X$ pro-étale over $U$. Let $\bar{q}$ be the image of $\tilde{q}$ in $U_\bar{k} \subset X_\bar{k}$, the base change of $X$ to $\bar{k}$. My goal is to show that it has trivial stabilizer in $\pi_1(U_\bar{k})$, the étale fundamental group of $U_\bar{k}$.

Honestly I am unsure where to start. I know that an element of the stabilizer is going to be an automorphism of $K_U$, the compositum of all finite extensions corresponding to étale morphisms onto $U$, that fixes $K \bar{k}$. My first thought was that an element of the stabilizer of $\bar{q}$ is going to induce an automorphism in $\operatorname{Gal}(\kappa(q) \mid \kappa(p)= k)$ just like an element of the stabilizer of $\tilde{q}$ in $\pi_1(U)$ will. I guess the hope would be that somehow we can look at this induced automorphism in the $\pi_1(U_\bar{k})$ case to show that any such $g$ in the stabilizer will be trivial, unlike in the $\pi_1(U)$ case.

Apologies if what I have so far is unhelpful or wrong: I am pretty stuck on this claim.